# Javascript Remove spaces object.hash

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

My object.hash has spacings in it and I would like to remove them.

My code is as follows

```
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a.section-link")


console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[0].hash) 
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[1].hash)
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[2].hash)
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[3].hash)


window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash).decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash).replace(/\s/g, '-');
    console.log(section)
  })
})
```

My console.log Outputs

```
Navbar hash #Introduction
Navbar hash #Census%20snapshot
Navbar hash #Proportion%20of%20women%20over%20time
Navbar hash #Recently%20trained%20workers
```

Current Error message for my window.addEventListener:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).decodeURIComponent is not a function
```

EDIT: Latest changes

```
 window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash).toString().replace(/\s+/g, "-");;

    console.log(section)
  })
})
```

Output: **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#Census%20snapshot' is not a valid selector.**

Latest Edit with HTML

```
<div class="sidebar"> 
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {% for block in page.article_content %}
        <li><a class="section-link" id="{{ block.value.header }}"
          href="#{{ block.value.header }}">{{ block.value.header }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

<div class="container">
    {% for block in page.article_content %}
    <main>
      <section id="{{ block.value.header }}">
        <h1 class="headline-text section-header" >{{ block.value.header}}</h1>
        <div class="header-bar"></div>
        <div class="case-study-body-container" >
          {{ block.value.description|richtext }}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    {% endfor %}


window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    // let section = document.querySelector(link.hash).toString().replace(/\s+/g, "-");
    let section = document.querySelector(decodeURIComponent(link.hash).replace(/ /g, "-"));
    let testLink = document.querySelector(decodeURIComponent(link.id).replace(/ /g, "-"));
    console.log('section', section)
    console.log('id', testLink)
    console.log('Link', link.hash)
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Welll...the error message is correct - `decodeURIComponent` is not a method on the Node returned by `querySelector`. `decodeURIComponent` is a global function.

Comment: Thanks, your input has been very helpful

Comment: According to the HTML standards, `id` attributes should not have spaces. Remove them throughout your HTML document, and where they are referenced in `hash` attributes.

Comment: @trincot my id attributes are being generated through a CMS, hence why I'm trying to use JavaScript to remove those spaces.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. `link.hash` will have spaces encoded as "%20", so you'll not find them with `\s` in a regex.
2. `decodeURIComponent` is indeed something you could use to replace those "%20" (and other escaped characters), but it is not a method on the String prototype, but a global function.

So here is how you could replace spaces with dashes:

```
let section = document.querySelector(decodeURIComponent(link.hash).replace(/ /g, "-"));
```

Demo:

```js
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a.section-link");
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[0].hash); 
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[1].hash);
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[2].hash);
console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[3].hash);

window.addEventListener("load", event => { // Changed event to "load" for this snippet only
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(decodeURIComponent(link.hash).replace(/ /g, "-"));
    console.log(section);
  })
});
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="section-link" href="test#Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a class="section-link" href="test#Census snapshot">Census snapshot</a></li>
        <li><a class="section-link" href="test#Proportion of women over time">Proportion of women over time</a></li>
        <li><a class="section-link" href="test#Recently trained workers">Recently trained workers</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="Introduction">Introduction</div>
<div id="Census-snapshot">Census snapshot</div>
<div id="Proportion-of-women-over-time">Proportion of women over time</div>
<div id="Recently-trained-workers">Recently trained workers</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, makes sense now. However, my console still outputs this...#Proportion%20of%20women%20over%20time

Comment: Can you confirm *which* `console.log` is outputting that? Sure, the line `console.log("Navbar hash", mainNavLinks[0].hash)` outputs that, but that line is not doing any conversion. Your question was about the error you had in the `forEach` loop. The `console.log` in that loop cannot possibly output that, as `document.querySelector` will return a DOM element (if there is a match), not a string. I added a snippet to my answer, with some invented HTML.

Comment: I can confirm that it is the forEach loop that is outputting that. I have posted a screenshot with my console logs, and have also updated my post with HTML to give you an idea of the structure. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: The part that outputs `%20` is `console.log('Link', link.hash)`, which is just outputting the `link.hash` value without any conversion applied to it (just like I said in previous comment). The other outputs are apparently `null`, which indicates that the corresponding DOM elements were not found. You should debug to see what value `decodeURIComponent(link.hash).replace(/ /g, "-")` has, and then check that you actually have  an element that matches that selector.

Comment: Since you posted HTML which still needs to be parsed by some templating API (resolving the `{{ }}`), there is no way I can tell what the expected `id` values should be. If you cannot resolve the issue using my previous remark, then please post the HTML without those `{{ }}`, but with the actual values that got injected at those positions (you'll need to inspect the DOM to see that).